# How to change the Value of a Widget in Flutter through dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i would like to know o can i change the value of a child widget in flutter if a certain condition is met, for example the color of an icon in the trailing

Here is some pseudo-code:

```dart
if(condition){
   trailing Icon(Icons.favorite).color = Colors.red[500]
}else{
  trailing = Icon(Icons.Favorite).color = Colors.blue[300]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is totally unclear , would you like to make certain modification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wanna something like this?

[image]

if yes, try this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool colorIndex = true;
  void _changeColor(val) {
    setState(() {
      this.colorIndex = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _changeColor(!colorIndex);
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.touch_app),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Click FAB to change color'),
                trailing: Icon(
                  Icons.favorite,
                  color: colorIndex ? Colors.red[500] : Colors.blue[300],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change anything under any condition you define. The most simple example is using `setState` to update a value that can be inspected during `build`. This value could change under any condition you like. Calling `setState` will trigger the UI to rebuild *(calls the `build` method)*.

Here is a Widget. It displays the text "Hello, World!" in the center of the screen. The AppBar at the top has a leading IconButton Widget. When the IconButton is pressed, it will toggle the color of the "Hello, World!" text. It does this by updating the state of Widget and toggling the value of the `blue` variable. The condition is: `if (blue) {}` or "if blue is equal to `true` then change the color." During the `build` of the UI, the code inspects the value of `blue` and determines what `TextStyle` to apply to the "Hello, World!" text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorChangeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ColorChangeWidgetState();
}

class _ColorChangeWidgetState extends State<ColorChangeWidget> {
  
  bool blue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
    if (blue) {
      style = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              blue = !blue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text("Hello, World!", style: style)
      )
    ); 
  }
  
}
```